# webgl translate javaScript

Tags: javascript, 3d, position, webgl, gl-matrix

I'm trying to translate object by using mat4 here..
I know how to rotate the object but I failed to translate the object.
I will be very thankful to everyone who helps me because I'm tired of trying to find a solution to my issue.

Important code here in javaScript:

```
var matWorldUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'mWorld');
var matViewUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'mView');
var matProjUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'mProj');

var worldMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
var viewMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
var projMatrix = new Float32Array(16);

mat4.identity(worldMatrix);
mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix, [0, 0, -8], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
  mat4.perspective(projMatrix, glMatrix.toRadian(45), canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000.0);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, worldMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matViewUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, viewMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matProjUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, projMatrix);

var xRotationMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
var yRotationMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
var identityMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
mat4.identity(identityMatrix);


var angle = 0;
    var looping = function () {
    angle = performance.now() / 1000 / 6 * 2 * Math.PI;
    mat4.rotate(yRotationMatrix, identityMatrix, angle, [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(xRotationMatrix, identityMatrix, angle / 4, [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.mul(worldMatrix, yRotationMatrix, xRotationMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, worldMatrix);
requestAnimationFrame(looping);
    };
requestAnimationFrame(looping);
```

---

Shader code here:
shader.vs.glsl:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 vertPosition;


attribute vec2 vertTexCoord;
attribute vec3 vertNormal;

varying vec2 fragTexCoord;
varying vec3 fragNormal;

uniform mat4 mWorld;
uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 mProj;

void main()
{
fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord;
fragNormal = (mWorld * vec4(vertNormal, 0.0)).xyz;

gl_Position = mProj * mView * mWorld * vec4(vertPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: *`I know how to rotate the object but I failed to translate the object`* - where did you fail? [`mat4.translate()`](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-mat4.html) would create a trnslation matrix.

Comment: var translation = vec3.create();
vec3.set (translation, 0, 0, -2.0);
mat4.translate (matViewUniformLocation, matViewUniformLocation, translation);

Comment: Ah no, see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a translation similar like the rotation, see the documentation of [`mat4`](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-mat4.html).

Setup a translation matrix:

```
var translationMat = mat4.create();

var translation = vec3.create();
vec3.set (translation, 1.5, 0, 0); 
mat4.translate(translationMat, translationMat, translation);
```

Then multiply the matrix to your `worldMatrix`, like you do it with the rotation matrix:

```
mat4.rotate(yRotationMatrix, identityMatrix, angle, [0, 1, 0]);
mat4.rotate(xRotationMatrix, identityMatrix, angle / 4, [1, 0, 0]);

worldMatrix = mat4.clone(yRotationMatrix);
mat4.mul(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, xRotationMatrix);
mat4.mul(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, translationMat);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, worldMatrix);
```

If you want to rotate first and then translate the rotated model, then you have to change the order, in which the matrices are applied to the model matrix:

```
worldMatrix = mat4.clone(translationMat);
mat4.mul(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, yRotationMatrix);
mat4.mul(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, xRotationMatrix);
```

If you want to a achieve a dynamic directional motion, then you have to change the translation vector dynamically:

e.g.

```
vec3.set (translation, Math.sin(performance.now() / 1000.0) * 2.0, 0, 0);
```

See the example:

```js
var readInput = true;
function changeEventHandler(event){
  readInput = true;
}

(function loadscene() {

var gl, progDraw, vp_size;
var bufCube = {};

function render(deltaMS){

    var worldMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
    var viewMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
    var projMatrix = new Float32Array(16);

    mat4.identity(worldMatrix);
    mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix, [0, 0, -8], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.perspective(projMatrix, glMatrix.toRadian(45), canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000.0);

    var xRotationMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
    var yRotationMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
    var identityMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
    mat4.identity(identityMatrix);  
        
    angle = deltaMS / 1000 / 6 * 2 * Math.PI;

    var translationMat = mat4.create();

    var translation = vec3.create();
    vec3.set (translation, Math.sin(deltaMS/1000.0) * 2.0, 0, 0); 
    mat4.translate(translationMat, translationMat, translation);

    mat4.rotate(yRotationMatrix, identityMatrix, angle, [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(xRotationMatrix, identityMatrix, angle / 4, [1, 0, 0]);

    worldMatrix = mat4.clone(translationMat);
    mat4.mul(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, xRotationMatrix);
    mat4.mul(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, yRotationMatrix);

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, vp_size[0], vp_size[1] );
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    ShProg.Use( progDraw );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw, "mProj", projMatrix );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw, "mView", viewMatrix );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw, "mWorld", worldMatrix );
    VertexBuffer.Draw( bufCube );

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return null;
    
    progDraw = ShProg.Create( 
    [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
      { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
    ] );
    if ( !progDraw.progObj )
        return null;
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.progObj, "inPos" );
    progDraw.inNV  = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.progObj, "inNV" );
    progDraw.inCol = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw.progObj, "inCol" );
    
    // create cube
    var cubePos = [
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0 ];
    var cubeCol = [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ];
    var cubeHlpInx = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 3, 7, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 0, 4, 5 ];  
    var cubePosData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; ++ i ) {
      cubePosData.push( cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+1], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+2] );
    }
    var cubeNVData = [];
    for ( var i1 = 0; i1 < cubeHlpInx.length; i1 += 4 ) {
    var nv = [0, 0, 0];
    for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 ) {
        var i = i1 + i2;
        nv[0] += cubePosData[i*3]; nv[1] += cubePosData[i*3+1]; nv[2] += cubePosData[i*3+2];
    }
    for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 )
      cubeNVData.push( nv[0], nv[1], nv[2] );
    }
    var cubeColData = [];
    for ( var is = 0; is < 6; ++ is ) {
      for ( var ip = 0; ip < 4; ++ ip ) {
       cubeColData.push( cubeCol[is*3], cubeCol[is*3+1], cubeCol[is*3+2] ); 
      }
    }
    var cubeInxData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; i += 4 ) {
      cubeInxData.push( i, i+1, i+2, i, i+2, i+3 );   
    }
    bufCube = VertexBuffer.Create(
    [ { data : cubePosData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos },
      { data : cubeNVData,  attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inNV },
      { data : cubeColData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inCol } ],
      cubeInxData ); 

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

var ShProg = {
Create: function (shaderList) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++i_sh) {
        var shderObj = this.Compile(shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage);
        if (shderObj) shaderObjs.push(shderObj);
    }
    var prog = {}
    prog.progObj = this.Link(shaderObjs)
    if (prog.progObj) {
        prog.attrInx = {};
        var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
        for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++i_n) {
            var name = gl.getActiveAttrib(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
            prog.attrInx[name] = gl.getAttribLocation(prog.progObj, name);
        }
        prog.uniLoc = {};
        var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS);
        for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++i_n) {
            var name = gl.getActiveUniform(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
            prog.uniLoc[name] = gl.getUniformLocation(prog.progObj, name);
        }
    }
    return prog;
},
AttrI: function (prog, name) { return prog.attrInx[name]; },
UniformL: function (prog, name) { return prog.uniLoc[name]; },
Use: function (prog) { gl.useProgram(prog.progObj); },
SetI1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1i(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1f(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF2: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform2fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF3: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF4: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetM33: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
SetM44: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
Compile: function (source, shaderStage) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript)
        source = shaderScript.text;
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader(shaderStage);
    gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
    gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
    if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : null;
},
Link: function (shaderObjs) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++i_sh)
        gl.attachShader(prog, shaderObjs[i_sh]);
    gl.linkProgram(prog);
    status = gl.getProgramParameter(prog, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(prog));
    return status ? prog : null;
} };

var VertexBuffer = {};
VertexBuffer.Create = function( attributes, indices ) {
    var buffer = {};
    buffer.buf = [];
    buffer.attr = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++ i ) {
        buffer.buf.push( gl.createBuffer() );
        buffer.attr.push( { size : attributes[i].attrSize, loc : attributes[i].attrLoc } );
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i] );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attributes[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    }
    buffer.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    buffer.inxLen = indices.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    return buffer;
}
VertexBuffer.Draw = function( bufObj ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i ) {
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i] );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    }
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i )
       gl.disableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
}

initScene();

})();
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision highp float;

attribute vec3 inPos;
attribute vec3 inCol;

varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform mat4 mWorld;
uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 mProj;

void main()
{   
    vertCol     = inCol;
    gl_Position = mProj * mView * mWorld * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform float u_shininess;

void main()
{
    vec3 color   = vertCol;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( color.rgb, 1.0 );
} 
</script>

<canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.7.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: iam write:
var translationMat = new Float32Array(16);

var translation = vec3.create();
vec3.set (translation, 10, 0, -1.0);
mat4.translate(translationMat, translationMat, translation);
its run  but didnt change the object position

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: @Alijamal Wait, do you mean that you don't want a constant translation, but a dynamic directional motion?

Comment: i need a constant translation

Comment: @Alijamal Ok, then it is something like `vec3.set(translation, 1.5, 0, 0); ` But in general the code works, see the example in the answer.

Comment: This makes me confused. I applied all the codes and I did not get any errors but only the translation does not work as required